# Cannot disable capacitor plugin logging in web inspector

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using Capacitor storage to get and set values as seen here https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage
Everything functions correctly however I am getting a large volume of console messages while developing using xcode simulator and safari web inspector, every time I get and set values:

```
>native Storage.get (#284123)
>native Storage.get (#284124)
>native Storage.get (#284125)
>result Storage.get (#284123)
>native Storage.get (#284126)
```

My app performs many hundred of these operations.

Tried disabling these logs as described here but still logging

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2438

```
"hideLogs": true
```

or

```
"ios": {
    "hideLogs": true
}
```

in capacitor.config.json not disabling

it even mentions it here in official docs, but doesn't work, any ideas?
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/reference/config

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/console

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. updating to help any other poor souls out there struggling with capacitor console.log torture in need of a solution...

```
Ended up going to native-bridge.js file for project

commented out entire functions for:
capacitor.logToNative
capacitor.logFromNative

cli -> npx capacitor sync
```

Thankyou capacitor for your pages of logs that clogged my system and overheated my cpu.. enough said now... please be quiet.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 7):

In Capacitor 3 you can use **loggingBehavior** config and set it to **none**:

```
"loggingBehavior": "none"
```

Comment: For those who (like me) don't know exactly where to place this line: do it in `capacitor.config.ts` in the root of `config` constant. See [Capacitor reference](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config)

Answer (score 2):

***Capacitor 3+***

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config#schema

*capacitor.config.json*

```
{
    "loggingBehavior" : "none"
}
```

This is **Deprecated now**: i.e. Capacitor 2

It is here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/console

*capacitor.config.json*

```
{
    
    "hideLogs": true,
    
}
```